# IndexedDB in Web Worker on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I am trying to use indexedDB in Firefox 12 in a **web worker**.

```
dbRequest = mozIndexedDB.open("mydb","test db");
```

However Firefox shows an error: *mozIndexedDB is undefined*

Tried few others such as `self.mozIndexedDB`, `moz_indexedDBSync` but to no avail.
It works great in Chrome using `webkitIndexedDB`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: approx' 1000 days after the question was asked ... i also need this functionality and found that firefox developer edition v37 supports indexed db in web workers so hopefully it will arrive soon

Comment: its supported now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into something similar a couple of months ago. Firefox doesn't support this (yet):

> IndexedDB includes both a synchronous and an asynchronous API. The
>   synchronous API is intended for use with WebWorkers (However,
>   IndexedDB is still not supported in Web Workers as of Dec 2011); while
>   the asynchronous API is intended for normal web use. In the majority
>   of cases where you use IndexedDB, you will use the asynchronous API,
>   therefore this article discusses how you can use the asynchronous API.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. I was confused by the fact that it works in Chrome. It seemed to me that Firefox has a more complete implementation of IndexedDB spec hence thought it should work in Firefox as well... I guess we'll have to wait...

Comment: Indeed, the WebWorker access would be the "sync" API and the only API supported is the "async" version. AFAIK no vender as committed to supporting the sync API. As those calls will be blocking it could be pretty horrendous anyways based on IDB performance we've seen thus far with the async version.

Answer (score 0):

From the IndexedDB Specification, the Sync API could be removed

> Features at risk
>
> The following features are at risk and may be removed, due to
>   potential lack of implementations.
>
> ```
> 3.3 Synchronous APIs
> ```

Also, note that you could use the asynchronous API inside web workers too.